# Injecting code into theme product page

Tags: magento2, module, theme, custom, product-page

The may well be too broad of a question, but I'm having extreme difficulty finding any answers. I want to know if its possible to add a phtml block/view to a product page when you have a theme installed without overwriting what the theme is doing, just injecting alongside.

Everything I've found references creating your own templates/theme which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do, more or less just trying to create a helper module that can add some extra content while also getting the benefit of a paid theme.

(Just to note, have been scouring Adobe's documentation and other stack overflow articles, if there is already an answer to a similar question, please link.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add some code to a product page without overriding files from your third party theme.

This can be achieved through a custom module. The following example would add a note from the custom modules template file below the add to cart button on simple product pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.simple.productpagenote"
                   template="Max_ProductPageNotes::productpagenote.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The following line of code targets the add to cart form:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.content">
```

Within this tag we insert our custom template file:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.simple.productpagenote" template="Max_ProductPageNotes::productpagenote.phtml">
```

The content from productpagenote.phtml is then rendered below the add to cart button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your point about theme overriding, but you can inject the block class and phtml from your custom layout theme like this.

```
<block class="Companyname\Vendorname\Block\Product\View\Custom" name="customname" template="Companyname_Vendorname::product/view/custom.phtml">
```

Comment: Describing this is difficult. For example, given an installed 3rd party theme that already fully replaces the built-in Magento product page, inserting an extra 1st party widget on the product page alongside the theme's replacement. Would I have to copy the theme's product replacement code and then override it with my own? Or is there a way to do an injection without fully replacing the installed theme's phtml template?

Comment: You can override the custom theme's phtml in your custom module. You can also take reference from @Max answer.